# I can't boot Windows after re-installing it; dual boot set-up

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Why is Windows 10 not booting? I had a dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 in different partitions. I reinstalled windows due to corruption, and repaired the GRUB menu via Ubuntu which was still booting. Windows still not booting. Any advice?
This is the procedure I used ti repair the GRUB
[GRUB Recovery via the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Comment: Have you ran `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thank you @Vijay. Apologies for the delay in response. 
I sorted this out by taking the HDD out and formatting it on another PC and then reinstalling windows before installing Ubuntu.